# "apple-app-site-association" file not working in Vue.js with nuxt.js framework

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apple-app-site-associate

I am working on a Vue.js with nuxt.js project and need to include in my site the "apple-app-site-association" file.

I did the following steps:

1. Include "apple-app-site-association" file inside public folder: "static"
2. The route in my site is: "https://my-site/apple-app-site-association"

Instead of the file being displayed in the browser when I navigate to the link, the file is downloaded

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but my front-end was in ReactJS.
Since, I figured out that the solution is not at all related to React but rather an Nginx configuration, I think it should work for your (VueJS NuxtJS) implementation as well.

Sharing the link to my answer-
[How to serve apple-app-site-association file on /apple-app-site-association page in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61756765/how-to-serve-apple-app-site-association-file-on-apple-app-site-association-page/70702879#70702879)